# What is parent_left and parent_right columns on Odoo ERP database?

Tags: database, odoo, erp

Does anyone know what is the usage of **parent_left** or **parent_right** columns in Odoo ERP database? As I can see there are already **parent_id** column which is useful. What I don't see usage for parent_left or parent_right. You can see them using below queries.

**select * from stock_location; 
select * from account_account**

Thanks

Comment: http://falsinsoft.blogspot.fi/2013/01/tree-in-sql-database-nested-set-model.html Maybe nested set_tree_model in a SQL table?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861436/parent-left-and-parent-right-in-openerp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The parent_left and parent_right are 2 special fields that are related
>   to the parent_id field. The purpose of those fields is to make queries
>   within the hierarchy execute efficiently: with parent_left and
>   parent_right, you can retrieve all the descendants of a node without
>   making recursive queries.

You must refer this link: https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+question/186704